# How to embed HTML produced by C# code in XSL?

Tags: c#, html, xslt, xsl-fo

I have XSLT that creates HTML from XML. There are several parts of the resulting HTML that I need to create by external  C# method (extension method).

1. How do I embed this C# method into XSLT (within what xsl nodes? I do know how to use common extension functions inside XSLT)
2. What should my C# function return? HTML-formatted string? With escaped HTML tags or without?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to return HTML tag soup not conforming to XML rules then you can only return a string and then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="pf:yourFunction()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`. If you want to build a node-set of nodes or a result tree fragment then check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e.aspx), it shows the mapping between the XSLT types and the .NET framework types e.g. if you want your function to return an result that XSLT sees as a node-set then use the type XPathNodeIterator as the .NET return type of your extension function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I'm going to use the first option. I've actually already tried to use 
disable-output-escaping="yes", but it didn't work inside the application. Now I know why!
In addition to this change inside the XSLT, it has to be verified that the Transform inside the C# code (which performs the transformation of XML to HTML by the provided XSLT) doesn't use XMLTextWriter, since it doesn't escape entities.
This:
http://www.stylusstudio.com/~SSDN/default.asp?action=9&fid=48&read=3838
helped me! I hope it will help someone else.